# Excel: exporting 1 row as a string

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I wrote this simple formula in an Excel sheet.

```
=CONCATENATE(A$1,"='",A49,"', ",B$1,"='",B49,"', ",
C$1,"='",C49,"',",D$1,"='",D49,"'")
```

It combines the cell value of the current row with the column headers.

I put it on E49 and if I copy-paste it anywhere in column E it adjusts nicely. I want to improve it and make it more generic and I'd rather not use VBA to keep it simple (i.e. install on any spreadsheet with simple copy paste of cell formula.)

FEATURE DONE:

- Automatically adjust to change the label in column headers.

FEATURE MISSING:

1. Adjust to add/remove columns by editing a few characters (e.g. having a "A:D" or "A1:D1" argument in the formula. )
2. Automatically adjust to add/remove columns.

QUESTION:

- Can I do that with a formula only? If not, is there any formula that could get close to the same result?

Comment: how do you want to specify the dynamic columns? Like a first parameter ("A..H") ? or "all columns up to the current column"?

Comment: @Thilo, whatever works if I can keep it as a formula. Best case would be that it guess that I need column A:D when I am putting the formula inside column E but it's ok if I need to tweak a few character to adjust to a new layout. Because now , I need to go through a tedious process of adding each column 1 by 1.

Comment: What is the expected output and what do you plan to use it for? Perhaps its worth looking at from another angle.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on how complex you want the formula to be.  I think its a less elegant solution, but you could theoretically build a huge IF(..) statement to test if column names exist.

IF they are not blank, perform the concat.

personally, I would use VBA, and toss it into an Add-in; that way it would open within any instance of excel on the local computer.

Comment: VBA and add in is what I am trying to avoid but as a last resort. I will go for it. Thanks for the "if" tip. However, My main concern is not catching blank columns but rather make i get all the columns, preceding current cell.

Comment: The IF() was to include all the columns that you have defined...  for example, if you had a range, say A1:Z1, and wrote an IF(A1='','',dowork); then any column not having value would be omitted... but if A1,D1,E1 had value, they would be included.

Comment: still, I would suggest VBA, for ... each with offset(r,c) will be much easier :)